# How to set srcObj for a newly created video element in react dom? Also how can I play() this newly created video element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I am trying to create a video element in my react component and then set a srcObject to it/ be able to play it after. So basically once the new video renders, I want to do `this.video.srcObject = 'a stream'` and `this.video.play()`. Is there something like componentDidMount but for the newly created video element?

```
class Video extends React.component{

   renderPeers = () => {
       return (<video ref={(video) => {this.video = video}}></video>)
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         {this.renderPeers()}
       </div>
     )
   }
}
```